# Is it possible to create HTML element attribute only in case of some condition?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, callback

Is it possible to decide on html element creation time excluding or including an elements attribute like setup a callback or not?

When using the ng-repeat flow I have some condition where I want to create the html element with a close-callback handler and in some cases the element should not contain a close handler definition.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" 
close="ctrl.close()">XYZ</div>
```

... or without callback ..

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">XYZ</div>
```

... maybe something like **ng-if**? Is something like that possible? The check condition is in the item itself. So during **ng-repeat** I need to check some items internal state like:

```
item.state === 'state1' ? add close handler : do nothing ...
```

Where I can add this condition check and how i perform the close handler adding or not?

Cheers

Comment: I'd use ng-show, but ng-if also works

Comment: Is this for angularjs or angular ? You tagged as angular but it seems you’re looking for angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom directive to solve this, here is an example :

Closable items are colored and have an `onclick` event listener (try to click on it).

To be closable, an item state must match `closable-state` attribute value.

> You must use single quotes around value when using `closable-state="'value'"` to prevent `value` beeing evaluated as an expression.
>
> If value is a hard-coded string, then you can remove `state: "=closableState"` from directive and simply use `attrs.closableState` to retrieve the attribute value.

Hope that helps.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
            { label: "item1", state: "state1" },
            { label: "item2", state: "state2" },
            { label: "item3", state: "state1" },
        ];
    }])
    .directive('closable', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                item: "=closable",
                state: "=closableState",
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var clickListener = function (event) {
                    alert("I'm closable !");
                }

                if (scope.item && scope.item.state === scope.state) {
                  element.addClass("colored");  
                  element.bind("click", clickListener);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

```css
.colored { color: red }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" closable="item" closable-state="'state1'">{{item.label}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Argv did it anwered your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of [Logical Operator Short Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" 
     close="item.closable && ctrl.close()">XYZ</div>
```

When `item.closable` is `false`, the `ctrl.close()` function will not be evaluated. Thus the function is conditionally evaluated based on the value of `item.closable`.